# Saving R ids in Shared Prefs

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, identifier, r.java-file

I'm currently using shared prefs in android to save some of my settings. This works well, but I came across a little problem with R. 
In my shared prefs I'm also saving some image resource IDs so I can acces them later (after the app was destroyed) on a new app start.
Now apparently once I add new resources to my resource tree and build the app again (aka update) the IDs change and I'm accessing a different resource with the ID that I saved before.

Do you have an idea/approach how to save the image resource IDs (or any other identifier) without loosing the link to them?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`R` values will change frequently and are not meant to be stable.

The best solution is for you to be saving something in `SharedPreferences` that has actual business meaning in your app, then map those values to drawables and other items that you might use for rendering that information. That way, if you decide that you need to refactor and rename those drawables, you don't break your data storage.

If you wish to be lazy or otherwise are willing to stipulate that you can never change the drawable names, you could use something like `getResourceEntryName()` on a `Resources` object (you can get one of these via `getResources()`, called on any `Context`), to find the name of a resource given its ID, and persist the name. You can then use `getIdentifier()` on a `Resources` object to look up the corresponding `R.drawable` value later on.

Comment: If I understood you well you mean that I could declare some final values that I hardcode in any class. then refer with these values to any "R.drawable.whatever." Right?

Comment: @binloan: I think so, though I am unclear what "refer with these values" means. For example, you could set up a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>`, where the keys are your logical business values, and the values are the `R.drawable` values for their corresponding images. You would store the keys in the `SharedPreferences` and look up their images at runtime as needed.

Comment: okay yes well we meant the same - my english is sometimes not as comprehensible as I want it to be. One last question though. You said that 'R values will change frequently' - does this mean even on runtime? Or only once per instance/activity?

Comment: @binloan: "does this mean even on runtime" -- no, only at compile time. However, any change in resources (add, remove, etc.) at compile time can affect `R` values. Since they change between builds, they are not a stable identifier to use for things like persistent storage. At runtime, for a given process instance, they are stable.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your resource name in shared prefs and retrieve the Drawable by :

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier(yourDrawableName, "drawable", getPackageName()));
```

Comment: This is another possibility, but since I'm not sure if my drawables will have the same name throughout all the development process it will probably be a lot to change, once I change. Thank you anyways!